# Image is rendered when I run jupyter notebook locally, but the image is not rendered when I see the same jupyter notebook on github

Tags: jupyter, image

I went on github issues to find solutions from people who has similar issue but none of them worked for me. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show an image on a GitHub page,

1. you will need to upload the image file to GitHub.
2. Then you must make sure the HTML is pointing to the correct absolute path.